# Eigenvalues for Sum of Two Symmetric Matrices (Special Case)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm interested in calculating the eigenvalues for the sum of two matrices. I've read several papers on bounds, but I was wondering if anyone knows of a method to find the eigenvalues for the following specific case:

Let $G$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix whose eigenvalues and vectors are known and $A = [1]_{ij}$ (the $n\times n$ matrix of all ones).

Is there any method to find the eigenvalues of the sum $G+A$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $A$ can be written as $uu^T$ where $u$ is the column vector of all ones. Consequently $G+A$ is a rank-one update of $G$, so tools like the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) come into play.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That was helpful. I'll see if I can figure something out.